# Has anyone ever TRIED putting 16GB DIMMs in a sandy bridge / ivy bridge motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, sandy-bridge, ivy-bridge

I am writing because I have a few Sandy bridge and Ivy bridge motherboards laying around.  Supermicro x9's, Q67, an intel H67 and an Asus H61.  Running VMs in some capacity on nearly all of them.

I'd love to be able to put 16GB DIMMs in them (while their max is 8GB).  I remember in the old 775 days I'd come across systems frequently that would be advertised as only supporting up to 4GB, but I'd try 8GB DIMMs in them and it worked fine (albeit, this described limitation may have conflated 32-bit OS limitations with HW spec).

So has anyone ever just TRIED it?  I don't have any 16GB DIMMs lying around otherwise I'd be happy to be the first...

Edit:  It appears this was addressed in the thread [superuser.com/a/1172797/19943](https://superuser.com/questions/1172769/installed-32gb-ram-and-laptop-wont-boot/1172797) - I apologize for not finding it before asking my question.

A quick summary of a vendor explanation:

*The main problem is that the MRC (memory reference code) - which is part of the BIOS - does not support modules based on 8 Gigabit DRAM components (16GB modules consist of 8Gb components).
The MRC code reads out the memory-modules SPD-settings and finds that this module is using DRAM-chips with 8Gb capacity. Next it tries to look up the settings for the memory-controller in a table, but can not find any entries for 8Gb chips in the table.*

Comment: @Biswapriyo - disagree - its asking for facts.

Comment: http://www.qdpma.com/SystemArchitecture/SystemArchitecture_SandyBridge.html is a bit too technical for me - but would imply that 16GIG DIMMS could work.

Comment: There is a bug/limitation in Sandy and Ivy Bridge (and earlier) processors that prevents them from using 16GB DIMMS. https://superuser.com/a/1172797/19943 basically you need Broadwell or later processors to support 16GB DIMMs

Comment: @AveryFreeman I had not closed this as a duplicate because the other question is quite different in that it is asking *why* something quite specific doesn't work. I'm not sure if this is should be closed as a duplicate, or if I should bring the salient points of my answer over here.

Comment: Well, even though it's a similar chipset, which I think is where the similarities exist, it is a different memory configuration, so maybe having more examples of exploring the same problem from different angles is useful for acquiring search hits when people are curious.