# Can I use Intel RAM on an AMD CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu

I'm building a PC and I bought an AMD CPU and 8 gigs of RAM, the RAM says that it supports Intel, can I still use it with an AMD processor?

Comment: Could you tell us what RAM is it, and the motherboard you are planning to insert it in? Most of the time, the AMD motherboard states which RAM chips are supported by it.

Answer (score 3):

Branding RAM as Intel or ARM is just marketing, for RAM is RAM. It's either compatible with the standards of your motherboard and CPU, or it's not.

Always go by what your motherboard indicates is the correct memory. Pretty much all motherboards have a product page somewhere that lists the specifications and what RAM was tested as supported,
although RAM not being on the list does not mean that it is not compatible.

Check that RAM against your motherboard specification for parameters such as Frequency, CAS Latency, and Voltage to ensure compatibility.

But as you may still go wrong because of unpublished specifications,
try to get the RAM from shops that allow returns.

Comment: @JakeGould: So why are you downvoting me? I'm only trying to dispel a misconception. You should rather downvote the post.

Comment: @JakeGould: "Silly" unfortunately is not a Close-vote option (although it should be). This post represents a misconception that is the result of marketing hype, not user stupidity. The question is not at all silly to the poster, which is why I think an answer is appropriate, and it might yet also help future readers facing the same hype.

Comment: Technically there is some RAM that is "AMD only". In particular DDR3 RAM based on 8Gb chips won't work on Intel chips before Broadwell. https://superuser.com/questions/1172769/installed-32gb-ram-and-laptop-wont-boot/1172797#1172797

Comment: @Mokubai: I suppose that in such a case some motherboard/CPU spec wouldn't match. Although, as noted in my answer (based on my experience in SU), an important spec can go unpublished.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use Intel ram on a AMD CPU, the only issue that can be caused by using "intel" ram is the AMD  CPU not being supported on the motherboard socket. Ram is universal for the most part as long as the board supports the standards (ie DDR4 only works with a board compatible with DDR4)