# GA-H97N-WIFI upgradeable to 32gb Ram?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

I have a GA-H97N-WIFI currently with 2 x 8gb sticks for a total of 16gb of ram.

I want to upgrade it to 2 x 16gb sticks for a total of 32gb of ram.

The page on the board is here: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H97N-WIFI-rev-10#sp

It says:

> 2 x DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 16 GB of system memory

does this mean that my board can support 32gb total or 16gb total?

I have the following CPU: "Intel Core i7-4770"

Comment: What processor do you have? If it is before Broadwell (5th generation) then it will only support a maximum of 8GB DIMMS: https://superuser.com/questions/1172769/installed-32gb-ram-and-laptop-wont-boot/1172797?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.6783#1172797

Comment: @Mokubai its a Intel Core i7-4770 ...

Comment: It's 4th gen (first digit in four-digit numbers), so it's already maxed out according to that question.

Comment: Sadly yes, you are limited to 8GB DIMMs for a maximum of 16GB total. Do you want to mark this as a duplicate or would you rather have a solid answer quoting more reliable sources?

Comment: @Mokubai ah damn, okay no worries. Its up to you, if you write a brief answer ill flag it as the correct answer so you get the points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed 32GB RAM and laptop won't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1172769/installed-32gb-ram-and-laptop-wont-boot)

Comment: @mikeysee - The good news is that, Mokubai already submitted an answer, just to a different question that answers your question also.

Comment: @Ramhound that question is related to my question but isnt the same question. I am asking about a specific motherboard. I have invited him to put a quick answer on here if he wants to, ill mark it as correct.

Comment: @mikeysee - Duplicate answers really shouldn’t be submitted if it can be helped.  The linked question’s answer is applicable and answers your question

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned my Mokubai in the comments to my question; I am running a 4th gen CPU thus am limited to 16gb of memory.