# Can I use AMD RAM WITH an Intel CPU & ACHIEVE THE memory SPEED ADVERTISED?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i5

I'm building a PC and I bought G-Skill Trident Z 3600 MHz 16 (8gbx2) (FOR AMD) RAM For my Z390 & Intel i5 9600k set up. Just stopped by micro center for a 650W power supply and an employee mentioned that since it’s AMD RAM it will only run at 2144 MHz and not 3600 MHz. Is this true? If so is there a way to make it run correctly or do I need to return it?

Answer (score 2):

No such thing as "AMD RAM".  However the memory controller on your i5 may not support the same RAM clock rates as modern AMD CPUs.

From your [CPU specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134896/intel-core-i5-9600k-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html):

[image]

Therefore you should expect it to run in DDR4-2666 mode (with lower latency than memory sold as "DDR-2666").  The salesman saying 2144 had no clue.

Comment: So is there ram that will run at a higher speed with my CPU? For example is there intel branded ram from G-Skill, that will run faster than 2666?

Comment: No, the DDR4-2666 is the maximum supported configuration on that Intel CPU.  You can overclock the memory controller... (then it would operate faster with the RAM you chose, potentially up to DDR4-3200 but the memory controller is likely to become unstable before then)

Comment: Okay, Thank you! So I should keep the memory I purchased and overclock to what is stable. Changing ram won’t benefit me?

Comment: @ChadSt.Hilaire - **Intel/AMD does not product DDR4 memory themselves.**  Any specific DDR4 module will support all (compatible) x86 hardware.  There is no such thing as a DDR4 module that only supports Intel/AMD hardware.

Comment: While you are right that there is no *real* thing that is AMD RAM there was, for a period of time, a memory chip density that worked with AMD but not Intel meaning that you could buy certain larger DIMMS that simply wouldn't function in an Intel system while an AMD one would be fine. This is where the "AMD RAM" moniker came about, though I do not believe it should still be relevant as the Intel memory controller was fixed in products starting in 2013 and the problem was only with DDR3. I have a link and Wikipedia quote in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1172797/19943).

Comment: @Mokubai: Still not "AMD-only RAM", that would simply have been "not-Intel RAM".

Comment: Returning to this thread to ask for advice on how to overclock the memory controller mentioned above with the ram mentioned above. I currently have a MSI MPG Z390 GAMING PRO CARBON motherboard paired with G.SKILL Trident Z 3600 MHz ram (FOR AMD). CPU Z shows the max bandwidth per slot at DDR 4-2132 (1066 MHz) currently.

Comment: @Chad: Start with the MSI official guide?  https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/pdf/MSI-Z390-Overclocking-Guide.pdf