# A way to run 32G RAM in an Inspiron 5482, declared for max 16G

Tags: memory, dell-inspiron, memory-limit

I recently bought an Inspiron 5482 2-in-1, having two RAM slots with one 8GB module and one free, and I'd like to determine the max RAM I can install:

- CPU: i7 8565U | Max CPU supported RAM: 64GB
- Crucial Configurator suggests a 32GB kit with two 16GB modules:

  > This part is 100% compatible with Inspiron 14 (5482)
- Inspiron 5482 manual:

  ```
  +-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
  |                         |                                                     |
  | Maximum memory          | 16 GB                                               |
  | Minimum memory          |  4 GB                                               |
  | Memory per slot         |  4 GB, 8 GB, and 16 GB                              |
  | -----------------------   --------------------------------------------------- |
  |                         |                                                     |
  | Configurations          | •4 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (1 x 4 GB)                   |
  | supported               | •8 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (1 x 8 GB)                   |
  |                         | •8 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (2 x 4 GB)                   |
  |                         | •12 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (4 GB + 8 GB)               |
  |                         | •16 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (1 x 16 GB)                 |
  |                         | •16 GB DDR4 at 2400 MHz (2 x 8 GB)                  |
  |                         |                                                     |
  +-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
  ```

  I always doubt a computer manufacturer's specs on memory, as most of the limitations are coded at the time the computer ships, based on the ram modules and OS, available at the time it ships *(my MacBookPro 2009 max RAM limit was 8GB and currently it is running fine at 16GB)*
  This time though, the computer manufacturer suggests the use of one 16G module but explicitly forbids two 16G modules together, and that is unusual.

Is Crucial or Dell Wrong?

- Could there be a differencee of CPUs between some early models reflected in the manual and later models reflected by Crucial Configurator?

Is there a proven way to install 32GB of RAM in an Inspiron 14 5482, or is there a hard-coded 16GB limit?

Has anyone seen a similar model with 32GB installed?

Comment: What CPU do you have? Earlier U-series Intel CPUs have 16 GB limit.

Comment: @gronostaj 8656U, I thought that it might be a chipset limit, but then saw the crucial option and that baffled me...

Comment: Fwiw Intel ark says that the i7-8656u CPU can recognise 64gigs memory, so it would not seem to be a CPU constraint.

Comment: The CPU is important. Before Ivy-Bridge Intel CPUs literally cannot support 16GB DIMMs due to a CPU hardware limitation https://superuser.com/questions/1172769/installed-32gb-ram-and-laptop-wont-boot/1172797#1172797 Later CPUs will probably be okay.

Comment: @davidgo might the limit be related to the i3 version of the laptop?

Comment: @Mokubai Broadwell U-series have 16 GB limit too, Skylake brings it up to 32 GB.

Comment: @francescoMM Without knowing the i3 CPU in question I can't know for sure, but I'd be surprised. I could not find any i3 8th gen ultrabook CPUs which supported less then 32 gigs.

Comment: @davidgo I confirm, Core i3-8145U is the CPU and it supports 64G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end Crucial was right. The 32GB RAM update (2x16) runs smothly with no issue. Even in this strange case, manifacturer's info was wrong

Answer (score 2):

**Manufacturers are always conservative.**

Crucial (& all the others) make their money by being right & will refund if they're wrong.

Anecdotally, my Mac officially supports 32GB. I've got 64 in it. It will actually support 96 or 128 with the right OS. Source: [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-twelve-core-2.66-mid-2010-westmere-specs.html)

Comment: This time, the computer manufacturer suggests the use of one 16G module but explicitly forbids two 16G modules together, and that is unusual.