# Boot crashing - does Z87 and Haswell support 16 GB RAM modules?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, windows-installer, haswell

I've recently tried to install 64 GB RAM (4x16) on a computer equipped with an i5-4670K and a Z87 motherboard (MSI Z87-GD65 GAMING). It's currently got 16 GB of RAM in a 4x4 configuration.

When I replace the 4x4 with a single 16 GB module, the computer gets stuck in a boot loop (never finishes POST). Adding another DIMM (be it another 16GB module or one of the 4 GB modules) gets it to GRUB, but trying to start an OS or memtest leads to either a hang, crash, or display corruption.

With all four 16 GB modules, I can get a live USB Debian install to proceed far enough that it lists the available memory (and it'll list 65536MB in that case), but it hangs shortly after as it can't find root. memtest86+ also shows 65535MB before it hangs. The UEFI setup screen shows 64GB, but if I enable the text-only POST screen, it shows 0 MB available, which could be overflow in a counter or something more serious. The BIOS is on the latest version.

I'm wondering what might be causing the computer to err out like this. The information about whether the system can support 64GB seems to be conflicting:

- In a comment on https://superuser.com/a/1172797, forest.peterson says that Haswell supports 16 GB per module for a total of 64 GB.
- On the other hand, the Intel specification for the 4670K, https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75048/intel-core-i5-4670k-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html, states that the CPU only supports 32 GB.
- Some review sites state that the MSI motherboard supports 64 GB (e.g. https://www.techpowerup.com/review/msi-z87-gd65-gaming/) while MSI's specs say 32 (https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z87-GD65-GAMING/Specification).

Is my motherboard simply flaky or damaged, or am I running up against a design limitation (of either the motherboard or the CPU)? And (although it may be too much to hope for) is there any way to get it to work at all with 4x16?

Comment: forest.peterson also said that Haswell used DDR4 which wasn’t true.  I have a Haswell system, it used DDR3, not DDR4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your
[manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7845v1.0.zip)
says this on page 1-4:

> **Memory Support**
>
> - 4x DDR3 memory slots supporting up to 32GB
> - Supports DDR3 3000(OC)/ 2800(OC)/ 2666(OC)/ 2600(OC)/ 2400(OC)/ 2200(OC)/ 2133(OC)/ 2000(OC)/ 1866(OC)/ 1600/ 1333/ 1066 MHz
> - Dual channel memory architecture
> - Supports non-ECC, un-buffered memory
> - Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)

And on page 1-15:

> Due to chipset resource usage, the system will only detect up to 31+ GB of memory
> (not full 32 GB) when all DIMM slots have 8GB memory modules installed.

This means that your motherboard cannot handle RAM sticks larger than 8GB.

I would suggest using the Crucial System Scanner from the
[Crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/)
to find what kind of RAM will fit the motherboard.

Comment: Crucial's System Scanner says 64 GB: https://i.imgur.com/AR6PS3u.png (I've blanked out the manufacturer info). It doesn't list any compatible memory at all, though.

Comment: Strange, the Crucial website lists [these upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/msi-(micro-star)/z87-gd65-gaming), where it only goes up to 2x8 GB. I suggest getting in touch with their Sales and asking about 4 such sticks (I'm 90% sure that this will work). Crucial sales are in any case guaranteed.